# Git shows current directory files in reference to top directory

Tags: git, git-config

I'll take advice on how to word this better...

I'm on `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`
Haven't updated since this problem arose.

Using this as the example directory structure:

```
Project-Container
  Inner-Directory
    Deeper-Directory
      File1 (presume this has indexed changes)
      File2
```

Previously, when I would`git status` from `Deeper-Directory`, it would show that `File1` was in the staging area. Cool.

But now, `git status` yields that `../../Inner-Directory/Deeper-Directory/File1` is staged. And even more annoying, a `git add .` will not add the `Deeper-Directory` files to the index. I have to do `git add ../../` to do what I would expect is `git add .`

So did I change some config somewhere to reference everything as from the top directory?

-- edit---

reiterating:

```
$ pwd                                       : /Project-Container
$ git status                                : Changes staged for commit: Inner-Directory/Deeper-Directory/File1
$ cd Inner-Directory/Deeper-Directory \
&& git status                               : Changes staged for commit: ../../Inner-Directory/Deeper-Directory/File1
```

Also, this only occurs for `Inner-Directory`. The siblings of `Inner-Directory` show their files as they should. `Inner-Directory` is definitely not ignored though, and I can add its contents to the index without problem when I'm in the `Project-Container`. Its just that git doesn't recognize that directory as a member of the repo when I'm in that directory.

Comment: `.` stands for "current directory". Running `git add .` from `Deeper-Directory` stages all files within that directory that are not marked to be ignored. There must be something you're not telling us...

Comment: It looks like you are actually in a directory that is a child of a sibling (a nephew or niece?) of Inner-Directory. This would be at the same hierarchical level as Deeper-Directory, but not actually in it...

Comment: The repository is on the `Project-Container` level. Any child of that is not .ignored should be included. Also, `git status` would complain if I wasn't in a git-tracked directory.

Comment: Maybe problems with case-insensitive file systems? IIRC mac file systems are a bit weird in that regard.

Comment: @knittl while that's possible, I doubt that's the issue since this was working correctly last week.

Comment: In another repository (with the exact same directory names even) this is working correctly. Which leads me to think its a config problem with one specific repo.

Comment: @user: if it's repo-specific config problem, diff your  `.git/config` files or compare the output of `git config -l` run in each repo.

Comment: the `core.precomposeunicode` option was false for my problematic directory, but switching this to true didn't help unfortunately. That's really the only diff (besides remotes and other project-specific attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Well I never found the problem, but I found a solution...

`$ mv Inner-Directory tempName && mv tempName Inner-Directory`

Not the most elegant solution, but now my indexed changes are shown relative to their parent, and not the top-level git directory. So it looks like this was not so much a `git` question as a Mac filesystem question. Seems like some link between `Inner` and `Container` was updated in a way that Mac could interpret, but git could not.

Thanks for the help, guys.